# converting multiple date formats into one in r

Tags: r, date

I am working with messy excel file with multiple date formats

```
2016-10-17T12:38:41Z 
Mon Oct 17 08:03:08 GMT 2016
10-Sep-15
13-Oct-09
18-Oct-2016 05:42:26 UTC
```

I want to convert all of the above in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I am using following code for the conversion but lot of values are coming NA.

```
as.Date(parse_date_time(df$date,c('mdy', 'ymd_hms','a b d HMS y','d b y HMS')))
```

How can I do it all of them together. I have read other threads on similar case,but nothing seems to work for my case. 
Please help

Comment: `parse_date_time(df$date, c('dmy', 'YmdT', 'abd T Y', 'dmYT'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I add `'dmy'` to the list then at least all of the cases in your example are succesfully parsed:

```
 z <- c("2016-10-17T12:38:41Z", "Mon Oct 17 08:03:08 GMT 2016", 
 "10-Sep-15",  "13-Oct-09", "18-Oct-2016 05:42:26 UTC")

library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(z,c('mdy', 'dmy', 'ymd_HMS','a b d HMS y','d b y HMS'))
## [1] "2016-10-17 12:38:41 UTC" "2016-10-17 08:03:08 UTC"
## [3] "2015-09-10 00:00:00 UTC" "2009-10-13 00:00:00 UTC"
## [5] "2016-10-18 05:42:26 UTC"
```

Your big problem will be the third and fourth elements: are these actually meant to be `'ymd'` and `'dmy'` respectively? I'm not sure how any logic will let you auto-detect these differences ... out of context, "15 Sep 2010" and "10 September 2015" both seem perfectly reasonable possibilities ...

For what it's worth I also tried the new [anytime package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=anytime) - it only handled the first and last element.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the times first makes it possible to specify only three alternatives in  `orders` to parse the sample data in the question.  This interprets `10-Sep-15` and `13-Oct-09` as dmy but if you want them interpreted as ymd then uncomment the commented out line:

```
orders <- c("dmy", "mdy", "ymd")
# orders <- c("ymd", "dmy", "mdy")

as.Date(parse_date_time(gsub("..:..:..", " ", x), orders = orders))
```

giving:

```
[1] "2016-10-17" "2016-10-17" "2015-09-10" "2009-10-13" "2016-10-18"
```

or if the commented out line is uncommented then:

```
[1] "2016-10-17" "2016-10-17" "2010-09-15" "2013-10-09" "2016-10-18"
```

**Note:** The input is:

```
x <- c("2016-10-17T12:38:41Z ", "Mon Oct 17 08:03:08 GMT 2016", "10-Sep-15", 
"13-Oct-09", "18-Oct-2016 05:42:26 UTC")
```